# How far back it's possible to get browsing history in Chrome

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

Google [claims](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95589) that 10 weeks of browsing history is kept available in Chrome for viewing in the history tab, and supposedly this is the exact same data that is available to a developer using the `chrome.history` API when developing an extension.

What's curious though is I frequently notice that Chrome still styles links as :visited even for pages that I'm certain I haven't visited in several months.

I tested this by doing a Google search for pages I know I visited about a year ago.  Sure enough, in the Google results page, those links appeared purple.  However, if I open up the history tab and search for that page, it doesn't appear.  This implies that Chrome's storing history way further back than 10 weeks.

I'm wondering if anyone's discovered this too and might know a way of accessing the the full history data, not just 10 weeks.  I have a feeling it's possible by directly accessing the application's sqlite tables, but I would imagine it's impossible for an extension to do that.

Comment: Are you logged into your google account when you search for the links you visited a year ago? It may be google itself, not chrome, that is keeping the history at that point.

Comment: I tried logging into my Google account in Safari but noticed pages I visited in the past weren't shown as visited with purple links.  So it would appear it's Chrome.

Comment: Hmm, is the browser itself logged into chrome sync? Do you still see the history in an incognito window?

Comment: @BenjaminKnight, No the sync obviously doesn't work on Safari, **it's a Google thing** which works only on Chrome. To verify you need to logout of your account in Chrome.

Comment: In addition to storing detailed browsing history of past 10 weeks, chrome browser also archives all URL visits. That is why links visited a year back also appear as purple in search results.

Comment: See http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Visited_Link for more details.